# Change class or opacity with AngularJS filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I'm using AngularJS filter and it works good. See my code:

```
(function () {'use strict';

angular.
  module('myApp', []).
  controller('WineCtrl', WineCtrl);

// Functions - Definitions
function WineCtrl() {
  // Variables - Private
  var self = this;

  // Variables - Public
  self.filter = {};
  self.wines = [
    {name: 'Wine A', category: 'red'},
    {name: 'Wine B', category: 'red'},
    {name: 'Wine C', category: 'white'},
    {name: 'Wine D', category: 'red'},
    {name: 'Wine E', category: 'red'},
    {name: 'Wine F', category: 'white'},
    {name: 'Wine G', category: 'champagne'},
    {name: 'Wine H', category: 'champagne'}    
  ];

  // Functions - Public
  self.filterByCategory = filterByCategory;
  self.getCategories = getCategories;

  // Functions - Definitions
  function filterByCategory(wine) {
    return self.filter[wine.category] || noFilter(self.filter);
  }

  function getCategories() {
    return (self.wines || []).
      map(function (wine) { return wine.category; }).
      filter(function (wine, idx, arr) { return arr.indexOf(wine) === idx; });
  }

  function noFilter(filterObj) {
    return Object.
      keys(filterObj).
      every(function (key) { return !filterObj[key]; });
  }
}

}());
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/wYfs4/)

But I do not want the others to hide when I chose an item. Instead, I want to change the style (opacity or something else) of the others.
What do I have to do?

Comment: you can use ng-class to add css effect to others which are not selected

Comment: @Niladri this is not an answer. Could you give me more detail, please? Thanks.

Comment: you can use ng-class on the repeating divs to set css class which meets the condition like below `ng-class="{checked: wine.category != 'your ng-model value of selected checkbox'}`

Comment: where `checked` class has some css like below `.checked {
  background-color: red;
  }`

Comment: BTW you have to remove this filter if you want to show them all `filter:ctrl.filterByCategory`

Comment: @Jelaloy - did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you cannot change only styles when using your approach.
Your approach is Adding/Removing elements from the DOM, therefore you cannot change their styling.
In order to do what you want, you need to show all element and use your filter function just to add and remove CSS classes:

```
function filterByCategory(wine) {
    return (self.filter[wine.category] || noFilter(self.filter))? 'show':'hide';
}
```

and using it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="wine in ctrl.wines">
  <div class="{{ctrl.filterByCategory(wine)}}">
  {{ wine.name }} <i>({{ wine.category }})</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo Using Opacity](http://jsfiddle.net/wYfs4/831/)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, your current implementation is showing or hiding the matching items - you'll need to modify your directive to include use of an `ng-class` to assign a class if an item matches; then within the CSS for that class style the items as you wish.

Here is the revised version of your `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="wine in ctrl.wines">
    <span ng-class="{'matched': ctrl.filter[wine.category]}">{{ wine.name }} <i>({{ wine.category}})</i></span>
  </div>
```

And a quick definition of the `matched` class that gets assigned for all items that match your filter:

```
.matched {color:red}
```

In this example, the font color of matching items is set to red. You can also do away with the unnecessary `filterByCategory` and `noFilter` functions, keeping your code cleaner.

You can see the full working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/fteo3ugd/